# Is there anything novel about Zuckerberg's Jarvis?

Tags: ai-design, intelligent-agent

Recently Mark got some attention from the media by stating that he had created Jarvis. Not that I'm against him or anything, but this Jarvis seems to have been done a hundred times before. He's done something which most developers would classify as a home automation system. To me it's more like he did it for the attention. I was kind of taken back by the amount of media attention he got. If you've heard of Jeremy Blum, maybe you may understand what I'm trying to imply here.

I'm just curious as to why he got so much attention. Is there anything technically novel about his system that sets it so much apart from previous ones?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is nothing novel about this system. The main hurdle he had to pass was problems that you will face when your system has a lot of integration points across various APIs provided by different vendors with messy and often outdated documentation.

As far as attention is concerned we live in a world where so called celebrities get attention for anything that they do. Remember that media have only one goal - More and more eyeballs aka more money and nothing else.

Comment: Word ! If you take a look at the video, it's much more entertaining than informing. I think that it's not really novel but maybe we can take a glimpse at the future plans of Facebook, which scares me a little if I'm honest...

Comment: IMHO I always feel like sci-fi stories/movies/etc are the worst inspiration for any engineer and scientist. They are thought of for entertainment and have nothing to do with reality and actual problems whatsoever.